# $\frac {f (0)}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f (k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{L} \{ f \} (2 \pi i n)$

Tags: laplace-transform, divergent-series, analytic-continuation, formal-proof

I obtained the very strange formula above and at begining I was just wanted know how to interpretate it. But now when I know what is this with help of @Carlo Beenakker, I am leaving it as a proof. BTW I found some [article](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.peertechzpublications.com/articles/AMP-5-141.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjDor-tpNb9AhXX_yoKHYGHAC4QFnoECAQQAg&usg=AOvVaw2L5byXDO356phO20CxHXRS) about non formal take of that theorem (I hope my take on this could be colled formal). I made some changes because I am ritarded and I realised that half of calculation was unnecesary.

**proof** Let $f(x)$ be some an analytic function with a given Taylor series. By using the theorem on divergent summation derived by Ramanujan, we can associate to it the convergent integral $\int_x^{\infty}f (t) dt $ so we can write the summation in terms of Euler–Maclaurin formula as follows
$$
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty}f (k)=\sum_{n=-1}^{\infty} \frac {f^{(n)}(x)\zeta (-n)}{n!}.
$$

We can use Riemann's zeta functional equation to derived some transformation of the above expression:
$$
\begin{split} 
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k) & = -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) \Gamma (1+k)\zeta (1+k) }{k!} \\ 
& = -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac { f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) n^{-k-1}\Gamma (k+1)}{k!}  \\ 
& = -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac { f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) n^{-k-1}\Gamma (k+1)}{k!}  \\ 
& = -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x) t^{k}(e^{-2 \pi i nt}+e^{2 \pi i nt})}{k!}dt \\
& =   -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t+x)(e^{-2 \pi i nt}+e^{2 \pi i nt})dt
\end{split}
$$
And now, for x=0, without any strange equations it is possible to write down formula as
$$ \frac {f (0)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f (k)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{L}  \{ f \} (2 \pi i n)$$

PS: I feel like. Is it all Euler-Maclaurin formula? Always has been. Watch this trivial proof of Abel-Plana formula

$$
\begin {split}
\sum_{k=x}^{\infty} f (k) & = -F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) \Gamma (1+k)\zeta (1+k) }{k!} \\ 
& =-F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) \int_0^{\infty}\frac {t^k}{e^t-1}dt}{k !}\\ 
& =-F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(x)(2 \pi)^{-k-1} (i^{-k-1}+(-i)^{-k-1}) \int_0^{\infty}\frac {t^k}{e^t-1}dt}{k !}\\ 
& =-F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+ \int_0^{\infty}\frac {\frac {f (x+\frac {t}{2\pi i})}{2\pi i}+\frac {f (x+\frac {t}{-2\pi i})}{-2\pi i}}{e^t-1} dt \\ 
&=-F (x)+\frac {f (x)}{2}+i\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f (x+it)-f (x-it)}{e^{2\pi t}-1} dt \\
\end {split}
$$

Comment: Is $\mathcal{L}$ supposed to be the Laplace transform? The Laplace transform can be thought of as a change of variable of the Fourier transform, and I think your equality is just Poisson summation with that change of variable made.

Comment: It could be. But then how to transform my equation into $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f (n)=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat {f} (n)$

Comment: Or differently. Is it posible to prove my form of equation from Poisson summation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is an answer to the question as it was originally formulated, it has now been heavily edited.*

---

I consider this formula in the OP,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f (k)  =   \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)dt+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)(e^{-2 \pi i nt}+e^{2 \pi i nt})dt.\qquad\qquad(\ast)
$$
This is *almost* the [Extension of the Poisson Summation Formula](https://doi.org/10.1006/jmaa.1997.5767) using [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), see Eq. 3.4 of the cited paper:
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(k)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\,dt=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\left(e^{2\pi int}+e^{-2\pi int}\right)\,dt.\qquad\qquad(\ast\ast)$$
The expression on the left-hand side is to be evaluated in the Cesàro sense, when the sum over $f(k)$ diverges (for example, when $f(k)$ is a polynomial). The formula $(\ast\ast)$ follows from the identification of the distributions
$$\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-k)-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(e^{2\pi inx}+e^{-2\pi inx}\right).$$

Now I can take an even function $f(t)=f(-t)$, and then I almost find from $(\ast\ast)$ the expression $(\ast)$, up to an extra term $f(0)$ on the left-hand-side.

---

Here is a check that a term $\tfrac{1}{2}f(0)$ is missing from the left-hand-side of equation $(\ast)$ from the OP: take the case $f(t)=e^{-t}$; then the left-hand-side of equation $(\ast)$ evaluates to $\frac{1}{e-1}-1$, while the right-hand-side evaluates to $\frac{1}{e-1}-\tfrac{1}{2}$, so there is a $1/2$ difference.

Comment: Yep, for even functions $f (t)$, it is almost identical. But the case is that $f (t) $ is not specified in such criterias

Comment: What I hope I did in **proof** section was giving some generalisation of Poisson summation. I'm saying generalisation because it turns out that Poisson summation is some specjal case of my equation, what I showed in section **proof of Poisson summation from my theorem**. This is why i am saying that I do not specify sucha criterias of $f (t)$ because in **proof** section it is not specified.

Comment: But I can't tell if that is truly some stronger theorem. I know that it implicate Poisson summation. But can't tell if the oposite is true.  What I want to know is if my form is equivalent to Poisson summation or is it stronger

Comment: it is stronger, since it applies also to functions $f(k)$ for which the sum over $k$ diverges; as I indicate in the answer, in that case one should interpret the combination "sum minus integral" as a Cesáro summation.

Comment: Whiiii!!!! Now my only wish is that Euler wasn't first and that calculations are correct. I am horrible at counting trust me. Edit: Oh.  So there is some issue. But only $f (0) $ is missing?

Comment: Ok, now I see it. My bad. I was thinking you are trying to say that my equation is just special case of Poisson summation for even function. But you showed that for special case of even function there is difference of 1/2f (0) with acknowledge of Poisson summation. Thank you for showing me that issue. I will try to find that missing 1/2f (0). I am self-learning and this is my first attempt with some promissing results and I do not always get all high-level proffesional things. Sometimes it comes little later